# TYPO3 default-not-found

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

[image: Extbase Variable Dump item array]

for every item is a default-not-found record but there should be the uid of the parent.

My task is to have a multiple select in event for category-items. Each category-item has a parent named category. The relation between category and category-item is 1:n.

[image: multiple select category item]

this is the TCA of the event:

```
'category' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:zimk_eventfilter/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_zimkeventfilter_domain_model_event.categoryitem',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_zimkeventfilter_domain_model_categoryitem',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_zimkeventfilter_domain_model_categoryitem.parent',
            ],
        ],
```

Currently it looks like this in Backend:

[image: category]

[image: categoryitem]

I have currently two categories "Studiengang" and "Status" if you create a new category item you have to select a category as single select.

[image: sql]

The entries in sql are correctly configured and stored as you can see.

I tried in the TCA of category-item to set the default value to 0 but it did not work and the record still remains as default-not-found

TCA of categoryitem:

```
'parent' => [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:zimk_eventfilter/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_zimkeventfilter_domain_model_categoryitem.parent',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_zimkeventfilter_domain_model_category',
        'default' => 0
    ],
],
```